# Is there a way to get tapply to work with two index values (or equivilent)?

Tags: r, tapply

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
index1 <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3))
index2 <- rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"), 3)
value <- sample(1:100, 9)
SEdata <- data.frame(index1, index2, value)
```

What I want is the maximum `value` for every *combination* of `index1` and `index2` (i.e., the maximum of all AX, the maximum of all AY, etc...)

I have tried using `tapply` like this:

```
tapply(SEdata$value, SEdata$index1 & SEdata$index2, max)
```

...but this obviously doesn't work.

Is there a way to get `tapply` to work with 2 index conditions or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: `for` loops are obsolete. Use more advanced/efficient methods such as `data.table`. `library(data.table);
setDT(SEdata)[, list(max = max(value)), by = list(index1, index2)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide the two factors as a list

```
tapply(SEdata$value, list(SEdata$index1, SEdata$index2), max)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the general construct here would be to use `list`:

```
> tapply(SEdata$value, list(SEdata$index1, SEdata$index2), max) 
   X  Y  Z
A 27 37 57
B 89 20 86
C 97 62 58
```

But your sample data isn't very exciting for this purpose :-)

(Numbers obtained using `set.seed(1)`.)